# Cron job in Magento extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've created a Magento extension that runs a task every 5 minutes or so using Magento's built in cron functionality but I can't quite get it to work.

My extension config (etc/config.xml):

```
<config>
    ...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <featuredtopics_getnewtopics>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>featuredtopics/cron::getNewTopics</model></run>
            </featuredtopics_getnewtopics>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

My extension cron model (Model/Cron.php):

```
class Sodapop_Featuredtopics_Model_Cron {

    public function getNewTopics() {

        // Stuff
    }

}
```

The cron job seems to start just fine, it just never ends. Am I support to return something?

**EDIT**
After closer inspection I found out I had an error in my script.

Answer (score 0):

call the cron.php a second time. first time to schedule in db. second time to run the actual scheduled task. have a look at chron_scheduler table in db. if the method is run you do everything right but your script doesnt terminate. it will terminate depending on your php script max runtime. just do some logging to see what the method does!

Comment: Thanks for your help, after some debugging I found an error in my script.